# Avoid to Long input in char array

Tags: c++, arrays

Greetings I'm tryn to something like a telephonebook in c++.
Now I wanna make a search function where you can type in what you want to search for.
Like Firstname or Secondname.
After than you can Type the char array what you want to search I did this with cin.
Now I tried to make an if clause that avoid an overload of the Char array where the input has been saved but it didn't worked so far ...

```
//string that you looking for
    char suchString[40];
    //Variable to select what kind of data you looking for
    int selection= 0;
    //should be true if string is less than 39 signs
    bool suchStrisOk = false;
    //will be true if string is founded
    bool foundStr = false;
    cout << "weahlen die aus nach welchen Daten sie suchen wollen"<<endl;
    cout << "1.Anrede\n2.Vorname\n3.Nachname\n4.strassenname\n5.plz\n6.Wohnort\n7.vorwahl\n8Telefonnummer\n";
    //what should function look for
    cin >> selection;
    cout << "Geben sie ein welchen Begriff sie suchen möchten" << endl;
    //what string should function look for?
    cin >> suchString;
    if (cin) {
        suchStrisOk == true;
    }
    else {
        suchStrisOk == false;
    }
```

these are the variables an the "Check" where I tried to avoid the overload but if I type in more than 39 chars my programm still crashes ...
Hope you can help me.

Sorry for bad english comments just translated them fix xD

Comment: In C++, a string is represented with the `std::string` type.

Comment: You are rigth :D like in Java sorry ^^ my teacher always told us to call a char array in C a String

Comment: In C, yes---a char array is a string. That is not the case in C++, where there is a built-in string type.

Comment: @alovaros If you have to use a char array, then checkout `std::getline()` that allows to specify a maximum input length.

Comment: lol :D didn't knew thos but thanks just started to work with c++ on monday first time

Comment: Thanks at first tried this won't work maybe I'll get it

Answer (score 0):

The if clause

```
if (cin) ...
```

Tells the program to check if the input buffer is *not empty*, NOT to check if it has too many symbols.
I guess one way to do what you want to is to save the user input into a temporary char array (or better yet a [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)) with a larger size, then check the contents of the input using *strlen()* like so

```
char input[255];
cin >> input;
if (strlen(input) > 39)
    // Error input too long
else
    //copy input to suchString
```

But that's really bad practice. Instead to avoid all of these problems you can and should simply use the standard library 'string' which not only provides a more dynamic variable for storing symbol strings - [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) - which takes care of most problems (such as the overflow), but also provides much more useful functions such as .length(), .max_size(), .find() and more.

Comment: And if I now write 256 chars I get an error message again :D not really a solution but may I try string class

Comment: Hence why I said "that's really bad practice".

Comment: didn't really solved my prob but u gave me a good hint :D input is now a string than I check if it's shorter than 40 signs and if it is I transform it back to char array